# Smart Contract "Fork"

Tags: contract-development, contract-deployment, contract-invocation, project-fork

How could I create a new smart contract token and copy the balance of every address from an old contract.

Essentially fork a contract.

I want to make this a one time function in the contract so that it can only be called once. Or even better do it during the contract creation.

Comment: Is the smart contract to be forked already written or are you able to change it's code before it's deployment in anticipation of a possible fork?

Comment: It is already deployed. Been deployed for a year.

Comment: Is it a standard ERC20 token? Is the `balance` variable public?

Comment: https://etherscan.io/address/0x7f2176ceb16dcb648dc924eff617c3dc2befd30d

Comment: Okay wait, I am going to write you and answer, but it is not as easy as you think.

Comment: Ok. @Grunzwanzling would you like some crypto to make the contract? Like 1 million. It is valued at about $1,000 right now.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/73505/discussion-between-brendan-and-grunzwanzling).

Comment: @Grunzwanzling Could you please check your messages?

Answer (score 0):

You can create a new contract with method to get every addresses in the token contract, then you can just copy it to your own array of address and then just call balanceOf function and get the balance of all your new address accounts. It's simple if you are copy a erc20 token.

Comment: I know that, but I am not sure what code to write. I was hoping to get some code.

Comment: You can use the ""call" function after you create a instance of your token contract with its address

Comment: You can see it. It is public. Go to etherscan it is called OhniToken

Comment: https://etherscan.io/address/0x7f2176ceb16dcb648dc924eff617c3dc2befd30d